# how do I have multiple barplots in one graph?

Tags: r, graphics, graph, plot

I would like to produce a graph that has stacked bars of the Area stacking the Season (summer and Winter) by HR (60 and 90) by year.  Basically along the X axis I want my two HR sizes (60 &90) to be side by side, but grouped by year (2003, 2004, 2005 etc).  And then the Areas for the 2 seasons are stacked on top of each other.

```
   Year Season  HR  Area
2003    summer  60  13419.50953
2004    summer  60  13825.55977
2005    summer  60  13628.62486
2006    summer  60  13098.44875
2003    summer  90  25836.8865
2004    summer  90  29908.79986
2005    summer  90  31709.97851
2006    summer  90  27996.521
2003    Winter  60  5622.281258
2004    Winter  60  9270.272772
2005    Winter  60  11299.37334
2006    Winter  60  15359.69352
2003    Winter  90  14500.94848
2004    Winter  90  27264.27162
2005    Winter  90  26040.42253
2006    Winter  90  38532.49895
```

Comment: See the examples in the ggplot2 bar help page http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_bar.html for some ideas.

Comment: thank you! will look into the page.  I didn't know ggplot existed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Year, y=Area, fill=Season)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    facet_wrap(~HR)
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks so much.  I need to learn that ggplot library.  Didn't know it existed.

Comment: @Kerry a good place to start is the excellent ggplot website: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/